# Checkbox itemrender of Advanced grid does not hold proper selections on next open event of tree in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have a checkbox in AdvancedDataGrid as GroupItemrenderer.I have selected certain child nodes in tree and closed its parent,later when I reopen the same parent node,selected child nodes are not those that i selected.How to retain the correct selections in checkbox.??

Also am unable to set the value for checkbox (GroupItemRenderer) by default from component and also unable to access the value for checkbox in Data property.

```
package 
{
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;

import mx.collections.ICollectionView;
import mx.collections.IHierarchicalCollectionView;
import mx.collections.IHierarchicalData;
import mx.collections.IViewCursor;
import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.controls.CheckBox;
import mx.controls.Image;
import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridColumn;
import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer;
import mx.controls.advancedDataGridClasses.AdvancedDataGridListData;
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
import mx.core.mx_internal;

use namespace mx_internal; 



public class CheckADGRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer
{
    protected var myImage:Image;
    public var status:String = "false";

    // set image properties
    private var imageWidth:Number   = 6;
    private var imageHeight:Number  = 6;
    private var inner:String    = "inner.png";
    protected var myCheckBox:CheckBox;
    static private var STATE_SCHRODINGER:String = "schrodinger";
    static private var STATE_CHECKED:String = "checked";
    static private var STATE_UNCHECKED:String = "unchecked";

    public function CheckADGRenderer () 
    {
        super();
        mouseEnabled = false;
    }
    private function toggleParents(item:Object,adg:AdvancedDataGrid,state:String):void
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            item.@state = false;
            toggleParents(adg.getParentItem(item), adg, getState (adg, adg.getParentItem(item)));
        }
    }

    private function toggleChildren (item:Object, adg:AdvancedDataGrid, state:String):void
    {

        if (item == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //item.@state = state;
            var adgCollection:IHierarchicalCollectionView = adg.dataProvider as IHierarchicalCollectionView;
            var adgHD:IHierarchicalData = adgCollection.source; 
            if (adgHD.hasChildren(item))
            {
                var children:ICollectionView = adgCollection.getChildren (item);
                var cursor:IViewCursor = children.createCursor();
                while (!cursor.afterLast)
                {
                    toggleChildren(cursor.current, adg, state);
                    cursor.moveNext();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function getState(adg:AdvancedDataGrid, parent:Object):String
    {
        var noChecks:int = 0;
        var noCats:int = 0;
        var noUnChecks:int = 0;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            var adgCollection:IHierarchicalCollectionView = adg.dataProvider as IHierarchicalCollectionView;
            var cursor:IViewCursor = adgCollection.getChildren(parent).createCursor();
        }
        if ((noChecks > 0 && noUnChecks > 0) || (noCats > 0))
        {
            return STATE_SCHRODINGER;
        }
        else if (noChecks > 0)
        {
            return STATE_CHECKED;
        }
        else
        {
            return STATE_UNCHECKED;
        }
    }
    private function imageToggleHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        myCheckBox.selected = !myCheckBox.selected;
        checkBoxToggleHandler(event);
    }
    var selectArr:Array = new Array();
    private function checkBoxToggleHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        if (data)
        {
            var myListData:AdvancedDataGridListData = AdvancedDataGridListData(this.listData);
            var selectedNode:Object = myListData.item;

            var adg:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(myListData.owner);

            var toggle:Boolean = myCheckBox.selected;
            if (toggle)
            {
                toggleChildren(data, adg, STATE_CHECKED);
            }
            else
            {
                toggleChildren(data, adg, STATE_UNCHECKED);
            }
            var parent:Object = adg.getParentItem (data);
            toggleParents (parent, adg, getState (adg, parent));
            //Alert.show(selectArr.toString()+"\t\t"+selectArr.length+"\t\t"+selectArr[0].length+"\t\t"+adg.selectedIndices.length);
        }
    }

    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
        myCheckBox.setStyle( "verticalAlign", "middle" );
        myCheckBox.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, checkBoxToggleHandler );
        addChild(myCheckBox);

    }   

    private function setCheckState (checkBox:CheckBox, value:Object, state:Boolean):void
    {
        if (state == STATE_CHECKED)
        {
            checkBox.selected = state;
        }
        else if (state == STATE_UNCHECKED)
        {
            checkBox.selected = false;
        }
        else if (state == STATE_SCHRODINGER)
        {
            checkBox.selected = false;
        }
        checkBox.selected = state;
    }      
    override public function set data(value:Object):void
    {
        super.data = value;

        var myListData:AdvancedDataGridListData = AdvancedDataGridListData(this.listData);
        //var adg:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(myListData.owner);

        var selectedNode:Object = myListData.item;

        myCheckBox.selected =  AdvancedDataGridListData(super.listData).item.show;
        //var adg:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(myListData.owner);

        //setCheckState (myCheckBox, value, Boolean(value.state));

    }

   override protected function commitProperties():void
   {
       super.commitProperties();
       var dg:AdvancedDataGrid = AdvancedDataGrid(listData.owner);

       var column:AdvancedDataGridColumn =
           dg.columns[listData.columnIndex];       
       label.wordWrap = dg.columnWordWrap(column);
   }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();

        var w:Number = data ? AdvancedDataGridListData(listData).indent : 0;

        if (disclosureIcon)
            w += disclosureIcon.width;

        if (icon)
            w += icon.measuredWidth;

        if (myCheckBox)
            w += myCheckBox.measuredWidth;

        // guarantee that label width isn't zero because it messes up ability to measure
        if (label.width < 4 || label.height < 4)
        {
            label.width = 4;
            label.height = 16;
        }

        if (isNaN(explicitWidth))
        {
            w += label.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth();    
            measuredWidth = w;
        }
        else
        {
            label.width = Math.max(explicitWidth - w, 4);
        }

        measuredHeight = label.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight();
        if (icon && icon.measuredHeight > measuredHeight)
            measuredHeight = icon.measuredHeight;
        if (myCheckBox && myCheckBox.measuredHeight > measuredHeight)
            measuredHeight = myCheckBox.measuredHeight;
    }


   override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
   {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        if(super.data)
        {
            if (super.icon != null)
            {
                myCheckBox.x = super.icon.x;
                myCheckBox.y = (unscaledHeight - myCheckBox.height) / 2;
                super.icon.x = myCheckBox.x + myCheckBox.width + 17;
                if (icon.x + icon.width > unscaledWidth)
                    icon.setActualSize(0, unscaledHeight);
                super.label.x = super.icon.x + super.icon.width + 3;
                super.label.setActualSize(Math.max(unscaledWidth - super.label.x, 4), unscaledHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                myCheckBox.x = super.label.x;
                myCheckBox.y = (unscaledHeight - myCheckBox.height) / 2;
                super.label.x = myCheckBox.x + myCheckBox.width + 17;
                super.label.setActualSize(Math.max(unscaledWidth - super.label.x, 4), unscaledHeight);
            }
            if (myCheckBox.x + myCheckBox.width > unscaledWidth)
                myCheckBox.visible = false;
        }

        trace(label.width);
    }
}
}
```

I am using 2D array as dataprovider to ADG.
 My post :
 [how to add an attribute to an existing array dynamically in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919428/how-to-add-an-attribute-to-an-existing-array-dynamically-in-flex) , is associated with the above post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't written any code to set the default state of the Checkbox based on data.

Generically, your itemRenderer's Checkbox state should be stored as part of the data.  When the 
itemRenderer is initialized, set the checkbox to checked--or not--based on the property in your data element.  When the Checkbox is clicked; change that same property in your data element.

This approach will sync your itemRenderer's display state up with your data.

If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to share some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: I have provided the code.Could you please give an example to use groupItemrender in ADG with 2D array as dataprovider to the ADG(Hierarchical data).